# How can I inline example field in OpenAPI spec?

Tags: openapi

I've got an OpenAPI schema (edited it to be a minimal working example):

```yaml
---
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Players API
  version: 0.0.1-alpha1

paths:
  /players/{id}:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Player'
                  - type: object
                    required:
                      - id
                    properties:
                      spec:
                        type: object
                        required:
                          - display_name
components:
  schemas:
    Player:
      type: object
      properties:
        spec:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerSpec'
      additionalProperties: false
    PlayerSpec:
      type: object
      properties:
        display_name:
          type: string
          description: The name of the player.
          example: LeBron
        environment:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerReference'
            - required:
                - related
          description: The environment to which the player belongs.
      additionalProperties: false
    PlayerReference:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          example: 'lebron-23'
```

and after I run: `redoc-cli bundle example.yaml` to generate the docs I can see:
[image]
(basically `id: lebron-23` is there -- i.e., the docs look as expected).

The problem is in order to make it work I had to add `example: 'lebron-23'` to the definition of a generic `PlayerReference` component but I'd rather move this `example: 'lebron-23'` line to this section instead:

```yaml
        environment:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerReference'
            - required:
                - related
          description: The environment to which the player belongs.
          <-------- add id.example here or something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `environment` is an object, an object-level `example` would look like this:

```yaml
        environment:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerReference'
            - required:
                - related
          description: The environment to which the player belongs.

          example:
            id: lebron-23
```

This example will probably *override* any examples from `allOf` subschemas (rather than *merge* with them), so make sure to include all property values you want to see in this example.